# How to assign to a bash variable the first result of locate?

Tags: bash, variables, find, locate

I can allocate a path to a certain variable from bash:

```
VAR1=/home/alvas/something
```

I can find it automatically:

```
$ cd
$ locate -b "something" .
/home/alvas/something
/home/alvas/someotherpath/something
```

**But how do I assign the *first* result from locate as a variable's value?**

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ locate -b 'mosesdecoder' . | VAR1=
alvas@ubi:~$ VAR1
VAR1: command not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to assign the output of the `locate` command to the variable:

```
VAR1=$(locate -b 'mosesdecoder' . | head -n 1)
```

(Use `head` to get the top `n` lines).

The construct `$(...)` is called *command substitution* and you can read about it in the *Command Substitution* section of the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) or of the [POSIX Shell Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03).

Answer (score 3):

[`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins), [redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) and [process substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) are your friends:

```
IFS= read -r var1 < <(locate -b 'mosesdecoder' .)
```

And using lowercase variable names is considered good practice.

It would also be better to use the `-0` flag, if your `locate` supports it:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' var1 < <(locate -0 -b 'mosesdecoder' .)
```

just in case you have newlines or funny symbols in your paths.

Comment: Yes deleted because you already have this answer which was posted not only few seconds faster it was also more accurate.